# Is the following equality obtained using algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> We have the following definition:
>
> - $C = \dfrac{Pr}{1-(1+r)^{-5}}$

Is it true that using this we can write $$P-\dfrac{C}{1+r} - ... - \dfrac{C}{(1+r)^{n-1}} = P\dfrac{(1+r)^{6-n}-1}{(1+r)^5-1}$$ where $n=1,2,3,4$ or $5$?

Just to be clear, the following equality is in my finance textbook and I'm not sure if they obtained it using economic principles or simply algebra. I think you can get the RHS by using $a+qa+q^2a+..+q^{n-1}a = a\dfrac{1-q^n}{1-q}$, but I can't get around the algebra.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{c_{0}:\ Initial\ Debt.\quad r = Rate.\quad n: Payment\ Number.\quad
> x =\ ?}$.

\begin{align}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rclcl}
\ds{c_{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{c_{0} + c_{0}r - x} & \ds{=} &
\ds{c_{0}\pars{1 + r} - x}
\\[2mm]
\ds{c_{2}} & \ds{=} & \ds{c_{1}\pars{1 + r} - x} & \ds{=} &
\ds{c_{0}\pars{1 + r}^{2} - x\pars{1 + r} - x}
\\[2mm]
\ds{c_{3}} & \ds{=} & \ds{c_{2}\pars{1 + r} - x} & \ds{=} &
\ds{c_{0}\pars{1 + r}^{3} - x\pars{1 + r}^{2} - x\pars{1 + r} - x}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\vdots} & \ds{=} & \ds{\vdots} & \ds{=} & \ds{\vdots}
\\[2mm]
\ds{c_{n}} & \ds{=} & & \ds{=} &
\ds{c_{0}\pars{1 + r}^{n} - x\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\pars{1 + r}^{k} =
c_{0}\pars{1 + r}^{n} - x\,{\pars{1 + r}^{n} - 1 \over \pars{1 + r} - 1}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
Since $\ds{c_{n} = 0}$:
$$
\color{#f00}{x} = {c_{0}\pars{1 + r}^{n}\,\,r \over \pars{1 + r}^{n} - 1} =
\color{#f00}{{r \over 1 - \pars{1 + r}^{-n}}\,c_{0}}
$$